# Sitecore ECM: User unsubscribing newsletter receives no confirmation email

Tags: email, sitecore, unsubscribe, confirmation-email, sitecore-ecm

My unsubscribe-link does not work properly. The user IS moved from Opt-in into Opt-out, but receives no confirmation email. Do I have to do anything to make that happen?

Note that I have not altered anything in /sitecore/content/ECM/[MyTarget Audience]/Standard Messages/Self-Service Subscription/Unsubscribe Notification.

In my footer I link to a existing unsubscribe.aspx I have found:

```html
<a href="/sitecore/Unsubscribe.aspx">
  <unsubscribe>
     <sc:Text runat="server" Field="Unsubscribe" Item="<%# this.DataSource. %>" />
  </unsubscribe>
</a>
```

In the email this is transformed into

```html
<a href="http://www.multi-wing.com/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_url=%2fsitecore%2fUnsubscribe.aspx&amp;ec_camp=A0D5584059504B85A3E3317B306A0411&amp;ec_as=B9844EF7C873423FA9C369890E9354E8">                          
  <unsubscribe>Unsubscribe</unsubscribe>
</a>
```

As I said the user IS being unsubscribed, but what do I have to do to make sure he/she receives an email confirmation?

Comment: I just checked that in Sitecore.EmailCampaign.config StandardMessages.UnsubscribeNotification DOES point to 'Standard Messages/Self-Service Subscription/Unsubscribe Notification'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've setup ECM with default settings it should just send automatically. If you have ECM sending emails then this should also be working.

Check your spam filter or your junk. This kind of notification get's junked all the time due to the format of the email.

Comment: Your are right! 
I was in my spam box!
But text is "You have successfully unsubscribed from ." (i.e. no target-audience name), allthough the Unsubscribe notification item has "You have successfully unsubscribed from [dollar]targetaudience[dollar]".
I expected taget audience name to be inserted automatically?